# ffmpeg .mpg to DVD (via DVDAUTHOR) 4:3 aspect ratio wrong

Tags: video, ffmpeg, dvd, tv, gimp

I have tried to get a 4:3 aspect ratio correct for DVD-TV presentation, but nothing seems to get it right. So, I made a TEST 448x336 px T.MKV movie that has a white background and two squares of different colors inside. The MKV  movie shows perfect squares and 72x72ppi-GIMP, but the Test.mpg square (72x81ppi) authored by DVDAUTHOR on the DVD is off. The 336px square is off 14.5"x13.5" on a 42" widescreen lcd TV display / Sony Blu-Ray player. The 10/11 scale filter is the closest, but it is still off. Code snippet follows:

```
ffmpeg BLAH -f dvd -target ntsc-dvd -filter:v "fps=30000/1001,scale='w=min(448,trunc((336*10/11*dar)/2+0.5)*2):h=min(336,trunc((448*11/10/dar)/2+0.5)*2)',pad='w=720:h=480:x=(ow-iw)/2:y=(oh-ih)/2',setsar='r=10/11'" -pix_fmt yuv420p -q:v 0 BLAH T1.MPG
```

The 4:3 standard way is way off. TV displays about 15.25"x12.625". Code snippet follows:

```
ffmpeg BLAH -f dvd -target ntsc-dvd -aspect 4:3 -filter:v "fps=30000/1001,scale=448:336,pad=720:480:136:72:black" -pix_fmt yuv420p -q:v 0 BLAH T2.MPG.
```

My goal is to get a 448x336 px, 4:3 aspect movie with the correct size and centered on the TV display. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question for this specific video. My large 336px square is square on my TV. 10/11 was too wide in width and 9/11 was too narrow in width. The height is locked or the same. So I measured an answer on the TV, but I do not know about other TV/DVD player combos. I also do not know the formula to be successful for all padded or non-padded videos, other aspect ratios and scaling issues. When time permits, would someone please answer with math? Code snippet follows:

```
ffmpeg FOO -f dvd -target ntsc-dvd -filter:v "fps=30000/1001,scale='w=min(448,trunc((336*8453/10000*dar)/2+0.5)*2):h=min(336,trunc((448*10000/8453/dar)/2+0.5)*2)',pad='w=720:h=480:x=(ow-iw)/2:y=(oh-ih)/2',setsar='r=8453/10000',setdar='dar=4/3'" -pix_fmt yuv420p -q:v 0 FOO T(8453-10000).mkv
```

Answer (score 0):

**Compensate for TV overscan = 5% (typically)** on a 16:9 aspect ratio video to —> NTSC DVD:
 
SAR × PAR = DAR
(SAR) storage aspect ratio is the ratio of width to height (in pixels) of the stored image or video.
 
(PAR) pixel aspect ratio is the aspect ratio of a single pixel in a stored image. In video, pixels are not always square. When non-square, the width typically uses more pixels (PPI) than the height, which is usually 72 ppi.
(DAR) is your display aspect ratio usually 4:3 or **16:9** -- this case.
A 720x480 (SAR **3:2**, and a **16:9** DAR is a given. The PAR is then calculated: DAR/SAR=PAR or 16/9/(3/2)=16/9x2/3=1.185185... The reciprocal of 1/1.185185...=0.84375. As it turned out, **ffmpeg uses different notations**. **The SAR as seen in ffprobe is really the PAR**. In any case, the typical notation for PAR (called SAR by ffmpeg) is normally shown as "sample_aspect_ratio": "32:27". **32/27**=1.185185...

An **anamorphic** (85.3333:72 pixels (non-rectangular) DVD video PAR=32/27 with a **16:9** display aspect ratio (DAR), movie will not fit on your TV screen properly if taken from a perfect 16:9 format. You will lose 5% due to overscan. Most commercial DVD's do not compensate for this fact. Don't tell Hitchcock that. So, if you have a 1280:720 or 1920:1080 (i) source, you can either scale + pad it first by 0.95*1280:720=1216:684 and pad it to 1280:720, then re-encode using the default -s 720:480 ffmpeg -target ntsc-dvd parameters **OR** scale once. Code snippet follows:

```
-filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale='w=min(684,trunc((456*27/32*dar)/2+0.5)*2):h=min(456,trunc((684*32/27/dar)/2+0.5)*2)':flags=lanczos+accurate_rnd+full_chroma_inp,pad='w=720:h=480:x=(ow-iw)/2:y=(oh-ih)/2',setsar='r=32/27',fps=30000/1001"
```

This scaling concept will get your video to **exactly fit on your 16:9 TV** screen -- without re-encoding! The '40/33' example often seen is nice but is not meant to be used in this case.

Comment: This is more complicated than it needs to be. In the notional width of 720, there are 704 active pixels in NTSC. And the NTSC standard pixel aspect is 10/11, which makes for a 640x480 display output. So, 448x336, if it's meant to be displayed full screen, should be scaled to `704x480`, then padded to `720x480` and finally `setdar=4/3` set.